# React nested routes issue

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a couple of routes setup using `Route` from `react-router-dom`.

```
<Route exact path="/dashboard/search" component={Search} />

<Route exact path="/dashboard/search/:uid/:sid/result" component={Results} />
```

**Problem**

The second route mentioned above is something I send to an email as a link. When I click that link. It opens up the link with url as expected but doesn't stay there and takes to the first route. Simply put.

1. 2nd route url shows up in address bar.
2. Then switches to first route.

As you can see I do have `exact` prop setup on this. Shouldn't they be differentiated? What could be the problem?

Comment: as i see your routes, nothing is going wrong with deceleration of the routes. you need to check the internal logic of the component, its redirecting from the internal logic of the component or container.

Comment: it would help if you give some more piece of code , wants to see whats going inside the code.

Comment: @MuhammadAteek. Thanks much for your response. I am cross checking it. I'll post it shortly.

Comment: @MuhammadAteek, Actually I do have a `button` within app. On click that page works perfectly fine.

Comment: it does not work only when you send link in email?

Comment: @MuhammadAteek, Yes. It works with the button using `history.push`. If I copy the address of the results page and open in another tab by pasting it (which is like simulating the link click from email). It doesn't work and takes me to the search page.

Comment: As you pointed out, that there may be a `redirection` logic. This actually isn't. because the `button` click works fine for the same routes.

Comment: what is your complete url included base path of the application, for example like localhost/zyx_url

Comment: try to add this in your webpack configuration 
devServer: {
      historyApiFallback: true
  }

And also set browser history on routes by like that <Router history={browserHistory}>

Comment: if it doesnt work then setup node.js server. which should send index or main page of the application on every request.

Answer (score 2):

**This code will help you**

```
<Route path="/Product" name="Product" >
    <IndexRoute component={Product} />
    <Route path="add" name="Add product" component={AddProduct} />
    <Route path="edit/:id" name="Edit product" component={AddProduct} />
    <Redirect from="edit" to="/product" />
    <Route path="detail/:id" name="Detail" component={DetailProduct} />
    <Redirect from="edit" to="/product" /></Route>
```

Comment: This is the proper way to declare nested routes in react.  if your component also have nested templates

Answer (score 0):

It will help you, you need to setup node server which will return main page of the application on every request.

[React-router urls don't work when refreshing or writing manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually)